# Find the limit of the sequence {$a_{n}$, given by

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the limit of the sequence {$a_{n}$}, given by$$ a_{1}=0,a_{2}=\dfrac {1}{2},a_{n+1}=(1+a_{n}+a^{3}_{n-1}), \ for \ n \ > \ 1$$

My try:

$ a_{1}=0,a_{2}=\dfrac {1}{2},a_{3}=\dfrac {1}{2},a_{4}=0.54$ that is the sequence is incresing and each term is positive. Let the limit of the sequence be $x$.
Then $ \lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }a_{n+1}=\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }a_{n}=x$
$$ \lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }a_{n+1}= \lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }1+a_{n}+a^{3}_{n-1}$$

$\Rightarrow x=\dfrac {1}{3}( 1+x+x^3)$

$\Rightarrow x^3-2x+1=0$

and this equation has three roots $x=\dfrac {-1\pm \sqrt {5}}{2},1$

So the limit of the sequence is $\dfrac {-1 + \sqrt {5}}{2}$.

**What is the other way to find the limit of the sequence?**

Comment: Where did $\frac 1 3$ come from? The equation you get is $x=1+x+x^{3}$. Perhaps you have made  a mistake in typing the recurrence relation. In fact $a_{n+1}>1+a_n$ shows that $a_n>n$ so $a_n \to \infty$.

Comment: $a_3$ is not $\frac 12$, it's $1+a_2+a_1^3=1+\frac 12+0^3=\frac 32$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy i really sorry for my typing mistake

Comment: @CiaPan sorry for typing error

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy one doubt always comes in my mind that how you people type maths ques and solutions so quickly in in this mathjax language. I takes too much time type any question and it sucks me. Is there any app to write it quickly. I have tried mathpix, mywebscript demo maths etc

Comment: @GirishKumarChandora When  I joined MSE I didn't know any tex command! (I used to do all my technical typing using Scientific Workplace). MSE put pressure on me to learn Mathjax. It took me a couple of weeks to get comfortable with Mathjax and I am now very thankful to MSE!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy so there is only one way that we have to type each and everything for our question and answer. But i am shocked whenever post a question , people gives answer quickly and how can they type so much fast?

Answer (score 1):

From $a_{n+1}=1+a_{n}+a^{3}_{n-1}$ we get for the limit $x$:

$x=1+x+x^3$, hence $x=-1$.

Since $a_n \ge 0$ for all $n$, we have $x \ge 0$, a contradiction.

Consequence: $(a_n)$ is not convergent.

Comment: Please change your answer. I apologise for my typing error

Comment: Why the downvote ???????????? In the first version of the question the OP has written $a_{n+1}=1+a_{n}+a^{3}_{n-1}$

Comment: sorry i made a mistake. I am admitting it.  I really sorry for down vote your answer . This mistake will not happen in future

Comment: Why the second downvote ??????

Comment: because its was not soln of question after editing. I really sorry for it and i made a question as op

Answer (score 1):

Each term is greater at least by $1$ than its predecessor: $$a_{n+1} \ge a_n+1$$
so the sequence grows not slower than the arithmetic progression $$(a_1 + (n-1))_{n>1}$$
hence it is divergent: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = \infty$$

Comment: 's Please change your answer . I apologise for my typing error. I made a correction in it

Comment: @GirishKumarChandora That's bad. You received some answers and some comments regarding your question. Once you substantially modified it, you rendered all that feedback wrong. If you made a mistake, admit it, and post a new, properly stated question. Don't hide your errors. This is a question-and-answer site, not a chasing-game playground. And downvoting good-faith and CORRECT answers just because YOU made a mistake is unacceptable.

Comment: i appologies and i am admitting my mistake